# PySide QMenuBar Cross Platform

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I have a PySide (Qt) application that utilizes an mdiArea in the main window and then populates this area with a number of QWidgets (windows).  These QWidgets have menu bars added to a vertical layout.

This works great on Linux and Windows, but fails on OS X, i.e. only the QMainWindow menu bar is shown.  A menubar added to a QWidget that is a sub window of an mdiArea is never displayed.  What is the normal method for supporting menubars in sub windows across all platforms?  Is it possible to put the menu into a toolbar?

Techniques in python or C++ are appreciated - whether a piece of code or a broader design pattern.

Comment: What do you mean by "fails on OS X"? Please add some details.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov Updated with additional information re: failure on OS X.